# Objective-C: Why do I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception when calling objc_msgSend with a parameter?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, exc-bad-access

I have got some problem while working on my own Button class in Sprite Kit / iOS 7.0. As soon as I try to call back the method with "objc_msgSend" I get the following error:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8)
```

Here's my Button class, where "identifier" is given back to the caller:

```
// Header File *.h
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) NSString* identifier;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, weak) id targetTouchUpInside;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) SEL actionTouchUpInside;

// Implementation File *.m
// ... this code is in the initializer method
NSMutableString *identifier = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
[identifier appendFormat:@"%d:%d", menuId, itemId];
[self setIdentifier:[identifier copy]];

// ... this code is called to inform the observer about an event
objc_msgSend(_targetTouchUpInside, _actionTouchUpInside, _identifier);
```

This is the callback method which is called by the Button as soon as a touch has been detected. This is the point where the EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception is thrown. The "identifier" is "nil", but only on the iPad Air, it funnily enough works fine on the iPhone 4S.

```
// ... this is the callback method in the object that instantiates the button object
- (void)itemTouchInside:(NSString*)identifier {
    NSLog(@"ID CALLED: %@", identifier);
}
```

I observed that it also works on the iPad when I call "objc_msgSend" ...

- without the "_identifier" parameter and/or
- with an "int" instead of "NSString*" as parameter
- with a predefined immutable NSString *identifier = @"fixed-string";

But I need to dynamically define the _identifier like shown in the code snippet above.

Any ideas why this works on the iPhone and NOT on the iPad ?

Comment: Why use `objc_msgSend` instead of `performSelector:withObject:`?

Comment: I think that problem in selector. Called selector doesn't suspect just one NSString* as argument. Try use `NSInvocation` instead objc_msgSend.

Comment: Don't use `objc_msgSend`, but if you really want to you should cast it to a non-vargs form with explicitly typed arguments. `((void (*)(id, SEL, NSString *))objc_msgSend)(_targetTouchUpInside, _actionTouchUpInside, _identifier);`

Comment: In addition to using performSelector instead of obj_msgSend, you could define "identifier" property as copy instead of strong. Then you don't need to make a copy yourself. Also "readwrite" is the default so no need to specify it. You can access the property directly by stating _identifier = identifier.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast response! I now tried to replace objc_msgSend with performSelector:withObject: and it works fine on all devices, although I get a "performselector may cause a leak because its selector is unknown" warning. But I have meanwhile read that it's okay to ignore this warning as long as the called method really exists... Thanks a lot!

Comment: @rmaddy: if you post your comment as answer, I will accept it - thanks again.

Comment: @salocinx I posted the answer as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you replace the use of `objc_msgSend` with the following:

```
[self.targetTouchUpInside performSelector:self.actionTouchUpInside withObject:self.identifier];
```

Note the use of the properties too. You have properties, use them.

As someone else mentioned, it is better to define the `identifier` property with `copy` instead of `strong`. Eliminates some possible (and difficult to find) bugs.

Comment: Someone care to explain the down vote? The answer solved the OP's problem.

Answer (score 1):

Create a protocol for touch events and you get type checking. All your problems go away. Or use blocks. Now it's possible that the target and the selector point to objects of wrong kind of classes.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will introduce a protocol :-)